Websocket Connection works with JavaScript but not with Java
I am building a simple websocket connection
I tried it with javascript for testing:
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket(
  `wss://public-api.birdeye.so/socket?x-api-key=` + apiKey,
  'echo-protocol'
)

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
  console.log('[socket] Connected')
})

the js code works just fine, I get messages from the websocket
but in Java the same code, doesnt work at all
import java.net.URI;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

public class WebSocketTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebSocketTest ws = new WebSocketTest();
        ws.testWebsocket();
    }

    private void testWebsocket() {
        String apiKey = MYAPIKEY;
        String wssURL = "wss://public-api.birdeye.so/socket?x-api-key=" + apiKey;

        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create(wssURL)) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                System.out.println("WebSocket Client Connected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                System.out.println("Received: '" + s + "'");
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                System.out.println("Connection Closed " + s);
                //  OUTPUT: Connection Closed Invalid status code received: 500 Status line: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Connection Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };

        client.connect();

    }
}

I get: Connection Closed Invalid status code received: 500 Status line: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
I just cant get a websocket connection in Java
I tried different libraries, Chat-GPT for help, same error
EDIT//
the code works, but not for that specific endpoint
I even tried it with python
any other websocket works with js, java and python
but public-api.birdeye.so only works with js, and not java nor python
